# How do I convert e.KeyChar to an actual character value when handling keyboard events?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, keypress, keyboard-events

All I'm wanting to do is get the actual character that is pressed whenever they key is entered for the event.

The only option I'm seeing is `e.KeyChar`which will give me the position rather than the character itself.

What I'm wanting to do is limit the values of the key press to digits between 0-9. The way I'm doing it right now is just `if((e.KeyChar < 48 || (e.KeyChar > 57)))`

This seems a bit cheap to just put in the values for 0 and 9, and I'd love to know how to get the character value itself rather than its key.

EDIT: Thanks for the input; so in general is there no way to go from having the `e.KeyChar`value to the value of the input itself.

I'd really like to take my event, e, and access the character pressed directly as opposed to using e.KeyChar to get a numeric representation of that value.

Comment: Don't ignore the backspace key!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simpler way of detecting if the key pressed is a digit or not:

```
if (char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)) { // doSomething(); }
```

Answer (score 2):

`KeyChar` is a [`char`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x9h8tsay.aspx) value - it **is** the character itself - 48 and 57 are the ascii values for `0` and `9`.

In C# you can refer to a character via its numeric ASCII code, or the actual character in single quotes. Therefore, your code can become:

```
if((e.KeyChar < '0' || (e.KeyChar > '9')))
```

which is exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

`e.KeyChar` is the `char` corresponding to the key pressed, not the position. The .NET Framework uses `char` to represent a Unicode character. If by "actual character value", you mean the integral value of characters 0-9, and not their Unicode values (48-57) you can do this:

```
var value = Char.GetNumericValue(e.KeyChar);
```

To limit the values of the key press to digits between 0-9:

```
if (!Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
{
    e.Handled = true;
    return;
}
```

For a more complete solution, that allows corrections:

```
const char Backspace = '\u0008';
const char Delete = '\u007f';

if (!Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)    // Allow 0-9
    && e.KeyChar != Backspace   // Allow backspace key
    && e.KeyChar != Delete)     // Allow delete key
{
    e.Handled = true;
    return;
}
```

Comment: `Keys` values are keyboard scan-codes, you can't (meaningfully) cast them to `char` values.

Comment: @Blorgbeard thanks for pointing this out. `Keys.Back` worked, because `Keys.Back = 8` and Backspace unicode = `U+0008` (8). However, `Keys.Delete = 46` and Delete unicode = `U+007F` (127), so it was erroneous. I've updated my answer to correct this.